# Azure ADLSGEN2 - API Error 400 - DatalakeStorageException The request URI is invalid

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using Azure SDK (Java) to create directory, upload files, move files in ADLSGEN2.

My input are very simple, it look like:

`path : /path/to/fileOrFolder`

But I got following Error:

```
com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.DatalakeStorageException: Status Error code 400: The request URI is invalid ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I share the solution here, as it cost me several hours to 1 day of debugging ... for just this:

The problem was that I had a leading Slash in front of the path.

Solution: Remove the first slash at the beginning of the path:

Replace

`/path/to/fileOrFolder`

by

`path/to/fileOrFolder`

It's the same pattern for all action : upload, create directory, rename, delete, ...

I think Azure SDK should do the normalization itself or have a more comprehensive error message ...

Comment: Same with trailing "/", e.g. DataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient("blobname"); DataLakeFileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient("mypath/") fails with same error. Must be "mypath" without the trailing slash.

Comment: A double slash in the file or directory name also trigger this error, ex.: `my//test/file.txt`